# rank(AB) vs rank(BA)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

How should I evaluate this statement?
I am looking for a simple way to prove or disprove this statement within the context my linear algebra course.

If $A$ and $B$ are $4 \times 4$ matrices such that $\operatorname{rank}(AB) = 3$, then $\operatorname{rank}(BA) < 4$.

Comment: $AB$ is not invertible. Can you connect this with determinants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the rank of $AB$ is not $4$, at least one matrix between $A$ and $B$ is not invertible, so the same happens for $BA$.

Comment: Let $f_A$ and $f_B$ the linear maps associated with $A$ and $B$. We have that either $f_A$ or $f_B$ is not invertible, hence $f_B\circ f_A$ cannot be invertible.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Look at the determinants.